# Apportable load Stuck on apportable spalsh screen

Tags: apportable

I have a completed xcode project that is running perfectly on iphone but when i runn apportable it seems to go ok but it only loads the apportable splash screen on the device and then no more movment. Please help.

Comment: did you check app logs? anything strange?

Comment: from what i can see runnig in debug mode there is no errors..?

Comment: I mean in apportable run. Open separated tab in terminal and run "apportable log" to see what's going on.

Comment: ok i have no idea what i am looking for now. any pointers on what i should be seeing?

Comment: i am very disapointed to see that people keep giving me negitve points with out helping. I have had gotten great help hear before. I have no expericne with java or android developing so i am now truly stuck.

Comment: You have problem in general and did not post any code or logs or something that can help us to understand your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

My problems were very similar and I found the initial nib loading was to complex for apportable i.e. too may views... try removing some views and just load controller, delegate and view and see if that helps... To be clear, I have confirmed with Apportable, they have just recently supported XIB's and DO NOT support complex XIB's.

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was using the `Developer Preview` version of the sdk, this is set up under `My Account` and configuring the project to use OpenGLES 2 rather than 1.

here is my sample project, with instructions: https://github.com/danmorton/apportable_test